# mongoose aggregate with array of string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a user collection like the below format:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f76ac1c337b875f3aff8cad"),
    "units": [ '1', '2', '3' ],
    "status": "true",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f76ac1c337b875f3aff8cad"),
    "units": [ '2', '3', '4' ],
    "status": "true",
    "name": "yyy"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f76ac1c337b875f3aff8cad"),
    "units": ['4', '1', '5' ],
    "status": "true",
    "name": "zzz"
  }
]
```

I am trying to find the query like below
input:  ['2', '3'] , should return all 3 records.

I have list of units like [ '2'] , should return first 2 records.

I am using aggregate query with facet, because required total count of records.

```
const id_lists = ['1', '2'];    
User.aggregate(    
    {"$match": { "status" : "true" , "units": { "$in": id_lists } },
    {
      '$facet': {
        metadata: [{ $count: "total" }],
        users: [{ $skip: 0 }, { $limit: 10 }]
      }
    })
```

Also I am adding support for sorting, select fields,  search the text(name field) and pagination. etc

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: ['2', '3']  are not in 3rd document. How does it return all 3 documents? And what is the problem you are trying to solve?